# How can I deserialize this XML to a useful data structure?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I am working with a receipt format that is returned to me as a "saml assertion".  This is a known and well defined format, but on my current platform, I don't have access to libraries that can deserialize the xml to the original classes.

I've determined that I will likely need to roll my own classes but given the format of the xml, I don't really know what the C# classes would look like or the definition and tricks needed to get it to deserialize.

The goal is that from the receipt, create a list of C# objects that I can examine.  I would like to retain the value in Format, in the Name node as well as the id.  In addition, part of what makes this challenging is that Statement consists of both subject and attribute elements.   One of the questions I would like to ask the list is, does the list contain a Assertion that has an Attribute node with "Gamma" having the value of 999.

here's the format:

```
<Assertion>
<Statement>
    <Subject>
        <Name Format="http://name.com/123/45/ProductName" Id="123">123456</Name>
    </Subject>
    <Attribute Name="Alpha">
        <Value>111</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Gamma">
        <Value>22</Value>
    </Attribute>
    ...
    <Attribute Name="Delta">
        <Value>3</Value>
    </Attribute>
</Statement>
</Assertion>
```

Comment: what about Linq to XML? : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Comment: This doesn't look like a well-formatted XML structure to me.  Attribute nodes should be wrapped in a single Attributes parent node.

Comment: I will be proposing Linq to XML as well as similar query based solutions, however I still need to present this approach as well.  +1 for attaching a useful link

Comment: @Kon, that is what makes this so much fun!  Besides if it were that simple I might not be here asking this question.  Fact is, I have zero control over the incoming xml.  It be what it be.

Comment: @Kon - That might be nicer, but it's not a requirement of valid XML. We can write an XSD that allows a complex type with a single 'Subject' element and then an unbounded sequence of 'Attribute' elements.

Comment: Linq to XML and nonserialization based approaches are officially off the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get your class structure started.

Here's an excellent blog post by Yogesh Joshi that walks through the whole process: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yojoshi/archive/2011/05/14/xml-serialization-and-deserialization-entity-classes-with-xsd-exe.aspx

Comment: Ryan, I tried this an encountered several errors.  This approach seems promising but not the way I'll be going.

Comment: @MedicineMan, I was worried of that after I read Kon's comment on not having well formed XML. Kyle W's suggestion is definitely the way to go. I look forward to seeing what you come up with.

Comment: I'm hoping I can duplicate the code in a sample. It uses a few techniques that are quite unfamiliar to me. But it works--

Answer (score 0):

As Kon said in the comment, the Attribute nodes should be wrapped in a container element.  I haven't found any good way to deserialize a list that also has other elements in it (or attributes, either).  You'll probably be forced to have your class implement IXmlSerializable and write more than you would otherwise need to.

Comment: I found some code (that I can't share without sanitization) that shows that we can deserialize this to a List<Attribute>.

Comment: Could you please sanitize it and post it?  Feel free to provide it as an answer to your own question.